# Spacing buttons equally on the app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 buttons on my app that are currently placed as shown:

[image]
I have changed my xml so that the height attribute is set to '0dp' and the weight is set to '1. This gives me the correct equal spacing but the buttons now expand to fill this space, as shown:

[image]

How can I modify my layout so I can achieve this desired layout? (Note: I created this layout in paint)

[image]

Current XML layout:

```
Here is my current XML code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="84dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLink"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/appointmentmanimenuicon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Appointments"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnaddAppoint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
    android:src="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
    android:text="Add Appointment"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnviewAppoint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointviewicon"
    android:src="@drawable/appointviewicon"
    android:text="View Appointments"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonably straightforward solution would be to use 'dummy' views to create the desired spacing between the buttons. You can then tweak the spacing by adjusting the different weights. Might as well get rid of the `LinearLayout` that wraps the two buttons too - generally it's not necessary to nest multiple LinearLayouts with the same orientation.

Try to swap out the `LinearLayout` with the two buttons for something like below:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnaddAppoint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
    android:src="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
    android:text="Add Appointment" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnviewAppoint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointviewicon"
    android:src="@drawable/appointviewicon"
    android:text="View Appointments" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give your layout desired height using layout_height="yourvalue" and arrange the spacing between using layout_margin="yourvalue"...